# Custom marker image on swift (MapKit)

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I use custom marker on MapKit

How can I change image width and height on custom Marker?

my code:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

    if (annotation is MKUserLocation) {
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "test"

    var anView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId)
    if anView == nil {

        anView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        anView.image = UIImage(named:"x2.png")
        anView.canShowCallout = true
    }
    else {
        anView.annotation = annotation
    }
    return anView
}
```

Comment: one option is you can set image size as per your need then you can display it.

Answer (score 5):

Try to use

```
anView.frame.size = CGSize(width: 30.0, height: 30.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentLocationAppleMarker : MKAnnotationView?

self.currentLocationAppleMarker?.image = //Image for Current Location Pin
```

MapKit ViewForAnnotation delegate should be like,

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    
let pin = mapView.view(for: annotation) ?? MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: nil)
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
           pin.image = //Image for Current Location Pin
           return pin
         } else {
             pin.image = //Image for Other Pin
             return pin
          }
     }
```